# On properties on a certain functional

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, cv.complex-variables, analytic-number-theory, integration

Consider the following function:

$$F(z) = \omega(z)\sin^2\left(\frac{c\Gamma(z)}{z}\right)$$

Here, $\omega(z)$ is a weight we have to construct and $c$ is a constant.

The following three conditions should meet for $\omega(z)$:

1. $$\omega(z)>\frac{1}{z},\ \forall z\in\mathbf{R}$$

( More generally this condition is added for divergence of $\int_c^\infty F(x)dx$ So ,  $\omega(z)$  can even be complex valued for real domain as long as the given integral is divergent )

2. $$\lim_{ y→∞}|F(x ± iy)|e^{−2πy }= 0$$
3. $$\int_0^\infty |F(x + iy) − F(x − iy)|e^{−2πy} dy<+\infty$$ for every $x≥1$ and tends to zero as $x\to\infty$.

> > Question : Can we Explicitly construct $\omega(z)$.

> > If anyone could omit the first condition and could find the weight satisfying condition 2 and 3 please mention.

(Is it even possible?)

See [this MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3570663/702232) ( see the part after UPDATE) and [this MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3689175/702232) for more details.

The question is inspired by following analysis:

\begin{align}f(x) = {} & \sin^2\left(\frac{π\Gamma(x)}{2x}\right)\\
\sum_{k=2}^p f(k)= {} & \frac{f(2) +f(p)}2 + \int_2^p f(x) \, dx \\ & {}+ i\int_0^∞\frac{f(2+iy) − f(2−iy)}{e^{2πy }− 1} \, dy +i \int_0^∞\frac{f(p-iy) − f(p+iy)}{e^{2πy }− 1} \, dy
\end{align}

As we can see the above summation is 'sort of' a prime counting function.

I'm trying to prove the infinitude of primes by trying to show that the above sum diverges as p tends to infinity.

In doing so I faced the following:
The complex integral in the RHS show oscillation of increasing amplitude. So to convert the summation into real integral I tried to attach weight such that the complex integral tends to zero as  p tends to infinity and so we only remained with real integral and some constant terms.

Comment: Do you want $\omega(z)$ to be a holomorphic function? What domain?