# Asymptotic of a functional as $x\rightarrow \infty$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, cv.complex-variables, integration, asymptotics

Consider the following functional :

$$
I(x,s) =\int_0^\infty\mathrm dy \frac{F(x + \mathrm iy, s) − F(x −\mathrm iy, s)}{\mathrm e^{2πy}-1},
$$
where $ F(z, s) = \dfrac{\sinh(\sin^2[π\Gamma(z)/(2z)])}{z^s} $.

Let us restrict $s\in[0,1]$

> > Can we get sharp numerical asymptotic of $I(x)$ as as $x\rightarrow \infty$?
> >
> > Also, can we get quantitative upper and lower bound estimations on the functional ?

Not trivial : see:

https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3570663/702232

[Construction of a certain weight for a functional to satisfy given condition:](https://mathoverflow.net/q/353795/145581)