# Construction of weight function to satisfy condition on given functional

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, cv.complex-variables, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers

Consider the following function :

$$F(z) = \omega(z){\sin^2\left(\frac{c\Gamma(z)}{z}\right)}$$

Here, $\omega(z)$ is a weight we are going to consider

The following two conditions should meet for $\omega(z)$ :

1. $$\lim_{ y→∞}|F(x ± iy)|e^{−2πy }= 0$$ uniformly with respect to $x$
2. $$\int_0^\infty |F(x + iy) − F(x − iy)|e^{−2πy} dy<+\infty$$ for every $x≥1$ and tends to zero as $x\to\infty$.

> Question : Explicit construction of  $\omega(z)$ .

We can say this question is Focused version of the following question (as asked in the reason for closing down the question) : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3570663/702232

Related but different:
[On properties on a certain functional](https://mathoverflow.net/q/353795/145581)

All types of suggestive comments and advices are welcome.

Comment: These minor edits intended only to bump the question to the top of the list start being annoying.

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki sorry for that but how could I make it reach to suitable people if it has no activity?

Comment: I am afraid you have to accept the fact that no one is able or willing to help. You can safely assume that everyone potentially interested in answering it has already read your question more than once.

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki Ok, thank you sir

Comment: Any updates or progress?